# Load cakephp controller without rendering default view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have to execute test controller without rendering default view test.ctp file. how i can do this in cakephp ? I have write below code and return below error message :

> Confirm you have created the file: Pages\test.ctp in one of the
>   following paths:
>
> C:\wamp\www\cakephp-2.6.1\app\View\Pages\test.ctp

```
public function test(){
    $this->layout     = NULL; // false
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->render('/pages/display2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->view = 'display2';` is all you need.

Comment: thanks for your help .. but not working .. it also now searching test.ctp file and return error - Confirm you have created the file: Pages\test.ctp in one of the following paths:

Comment: i just need to load display2.ctp ... but i also force to load test.ctp file .. that i have not created. so it give me error...

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewPath to set where the app should look for view to render.

```
public function test() {
    $this->layout = NULL;
    $this->viewPath = 'MY/PATH';  //app/View/MY/PATH/
    $this->render('mytest'); //app/View/MY/PATH/mytest.ctp
}
```

Comment: Beware of using Controller::render when it isn't necessary. That function will immediately end the action in progress and proceed to the beforeRender callback, which can have unintended consequences.

Comment: if you call it as last item in your controller action, then i don't see any problems, is it not Controller doing it anyway internally with the "default" view in this case the test.ctp ?